# MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I have this MPMoviePlayerController which is supposed to play a movie. So when I create the view, I init the player but I don't set a content url immediately as I don't have it. So then I call a method which goes and fetches the video url (I have it print with NSLog and tested it out manually in Safari and it works). Once I get the url, I set it as the content url of the player and call prepareToPlay. Now the problem is, the method I assigned with MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification isn't being called.

So I've narrowed it down. The url to the video I set is valid. When I call prepareToPlay after I set the url to the video, it doesn't work. But if I manually past the SAME url with the exact same code, it works. I put the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/TechGeniusApps/PSBN/blob/master/PSBN/PSBN/PSBNPlayer.m). Any help would be nice

Comment: Can you confirm that you're listening for the notification on the same thread you're adding the observer?

Comment: Yes. Everything (but the downloading of the json file) is not threaded so its on the main thread. The github link takes you directly to the file.